# Covert fetch to axios in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I need some help in replacing fetch with axios here

```
export const fetchSecret = async (secretName) => {
    const token = await getFunctionAppToken();
    const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    };
    const url = `${blbl.GetSecretFromVault}?secretName=${secretName}`;

    return Promise.all([fetch(url, { method: "get", headers })])
        .then(([response]) => {
            const res = response.text();
            return res;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
};
```

I am stuck at the line of const res = response.text() for axios.

```
return Promise.all([axios.get(url, { headers })])
            .then(([response]) => {
                const res = ??????????
                return res;
```

Comment: Axios automatically parses the response body stream as `data`, see [response schema](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema). You just want `return response.data`. Why are you using `Promise.all()`? Why switch from Fetch to Axios?

Comment: @Phil switching from fetch to axios is a different conversation because of some challenges in mocking fetch in jest(a totally different conversation). I do not want to change the implementation of the code here to avoid breaking changes. Here I think res is a A Promise that resolves with a String. I want something like that with axios. data would not be a Promise but a json object.

Comment: FYI there are many ways to [mock fetch](https://www.leighhalliday.com/mock-fetch-jest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios automatically parses the response body stream as `data`, see [response schema](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema#:%7E:text=by%20the%20server-,data,-%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20//%20%60status%60%20is%20the).

You can also inform Axios to expect a text response via the [`responseType`](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config#:%7E:text=responseType%3A%20%27json%27%2C%20//%20default) option.

Finally, I always preference using the [`params`](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config#:%7E:text=in%20the%20URL.-,params,-%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ID%3A%2012345%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20//%20%60paramsSerializer) option for passing query parameters as it ensures proper URL-encoding.

```js
export const fetchSecret = async (secretName) =>
  (await axios.get(blbl.GetSecretFromVault, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${await getFunctionAppToken()}`
    },
    params: { secretName },
    responseType: "text"
  })).data
```

I don't know why you were using `Promise.all()` so have omitted it.

Your `.catch()` was also redundant so it's not included either.

---

The `(await axios.get(...)).data` is just a shorter version of

```js
const response = await axios.get(...)
return response.data
```

or without `await`...

```js
return axios.get(...).then(response => response.data)
```